# Google Apps Script and Google migration Api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-email-migration

I am newbie 
I want to create a code in Google Apps Script that will do the following

```
1. Create some test labels in my Mail box
2. Then accordingly fetch these mails in User's drive using Google cloud SQL (i have used script db)
3. Once a folder for a label is created change the owner of that folder to admin of domain
4. Now i have to import all these email from drive to Admin's mailbox using Email migration Api
```

I have done till `step 3` . I am not sure  how to do the `4th part` through coding.Can anyone suggest